# Linux from Scratch 5.7.2 Toolchain sanity check

Tags: linux, linux-from-scratch

I started the Project "Linux from Scratch" some time ago. First I started with Ubuntu 15.10 64bit and did everything according to the PDF-File. By the Check in paragraph 5.7.2, it didn't worked. Afterwards I started all over again, with CentOS 7.2 but it works neither.In both attempts i got no Errors while compiling and installing the previous packages.

Input:

```
echo 'int main(){}' > dummy.c
$LFS_TGT-gcc dummy.c
```

Output:

```
/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Input:

```
readelf -l a.out | grep ': /tools'
```

Output:

```
readelf: Error: 'a.out': No such file
```

I found no solution that worked in StackOverFlow or different platforms.

Here my Output of the [version-check.sh](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/prologue/hostreqs.html):

```
lfs:~$ bash version-check.sh
bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release
/bin/sh -> /usr/bin/bash
Binutils: version 2.23.52.0.1-55.el7 20130226
bison (GNU Bison) 2.7
/usr/bin/yacc -> /usr/bin/bison
bzip2,  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.
Coreutils:  8.22
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.3
find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11
GNU Awk 4.0.2
/usr/bin/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
(GNU libc) 2.17
grep (GNU grep) 2.20
gzip 1.5
Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015
m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.16
GNU Make 3.82
GNU patch 2.7.1
Perl version='5.16.3';
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
makeinfo (GNU texinfo) 5.1
xz (XZ Utils) 5.1.2alpha
g++ compilation OK
```

My ~/.bashrc of the LSF User:

```
set +h
umask 022
LFS=/mnt/lfs
LC_ALL=POSIX
LFS_TGT=$(uname -m)-lfs-linux-gnu
PATH=/tools/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
export LFS LC_ALL LFS_TGT PATH
```

My ~/.bash_profile of the LFS User

```
exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i was astonished when first glancing at 'I started the Project...', after some time i realized that you mean you started to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when you've not installed the `Binutils` package properly. `ld` is provided by the `binutils` pacakage.

Please adhere to the steps provided in the book becuase if you deviate even a little it'll cause such errors.